# Can a Sharepoint Web Database Lookup Field use a query?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I'm working with this table and want to offer the user a Lookup list in one column. I can do this easy if I want to use a whole table.

But I want to show in this lookup just a subset of data.

Like this: `SELECT ID, Name FROM Items WHERE Type = 'SomeType'`

I have a query, but when I go into Lookup Wizard, I cannot select Queries. Why is this?

This is Sharepoint 2010, editing the Web Database in Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a continues form then you would simply drop in a combo box control for one of the columns and then you can build your SQL as you have using the query builder.

For most access applications it really never was very practical to allow users to open and edit data by using tables directly anyway.

And for published web applications you not even allowed to do as such on the web side (so you can edit tables client side, but not web side in a browser).

Using a continues form here should work just fine. So drop in a combo box, build your query as you have. Set number of columns to 2 and bind this combo box to whatever the underlying column is that this first ID value is to be saved to, and you off to the races.